# How to style focus outline for accessibility purposes

Tags: html, css, focus, accessibility

I'm trying to style the outline of the field when in focus because my current outline is very hard to see. I know that some html elements are focusable by default, so I'm not quite sure to what element to attach the outline style.

Do I need to target all the potentially focusable elements? Like

```
a:focus, button:focus {outline: 1px solid white; }
```

(including all the other elements)? This does not seem like the right method.

I have tried searching for the answer and all I can find is that outline must not be `none` but other than then, I haven't found anything else.

Comment: Just go `:focus {outline: 1px solid white; }` to target all focussable elements. No need to specify elements. Btw, this is short for `*:focus {outline: 1px solid white; }`.

Comment: When I do that (target :focus), then some elements get my chosen style, but some don't. Like my navbar links don't get this styling applied.

Comment: Create a pen or fiddle showing that.

Comment: I'll do that, sorry for not being prepared.

Comment: I know why now, it was over-written by normalize.css, where the outline is styled as 'thin dotted'. Still not sure why :focus didn't over-write normalize.css, though. My stylesheet is linked after normalize. Anyway, it works now, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just go

```
:focus { outline: 1px solid white; }
```

to target all focussable elements. No need to specify those elements explicitly.

Btw, this is short for

```
*:focus { outline: 1px solid white; }
```

Comment: What about things on white backgrounds?

Comment: OP hasn't asked for that. If you don't know what to do in that case, I recommend taking a beginner's course in CSS.

Comment: It seems like in most non-trivial cases it will be required for a11y. No need for snark.